# Adding titlesec package makes nameref show wrong caption

Tags: hyperref, titlesec

After upgrading from Debian 11 (*pdfTeX 3.14159265-2.6-1.40.21 (TeX Live 2020/Debian)*) to Debian 12 (*pdfTeX 3.141592653-2.6-1.40.24 (TeX Live 2022/Debian)), some `\nameref` invocations show the wrong title.

When creating a minimized test case, I see that if I disable the *titlesec* package, the label then shows correctly. Am I doing something wrong here?

```
\pdfobjcompresslevel=1
\documentclass[a4paper,twoside,openany,oldfontcommands,11pt,english]{memoir}

\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage[english]{isodate}
\usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
\usepackage{ifthen}
\usepackage{pdfpages}

\begin{document}

\section{How to Use This Manual}
\label{sec:howtouse}

\hyperref[subsec:osupdate]{\ref*{subsec:osupdate} \textbf{\nameref*{subsec:osupdate}}}
explains how to upgrade the software on the product.

\chapter{USER INTERFACE}
\label{ch:gui}

Blah blah blah

\section{Data}
\label{sec:data}

Blah blah blah

\subsection{Data --- OS Update}
\label{subsec:osupdate}

Blah blah blah

\end{document}
```

Building this with `latexmk -pdf try.tex` with Debian 12, I get:

> 1.1 USER INTERFACE explains how to upgrade the software on the product.

Whereas I expect the Debian 11 output:

> 1.1 Data — OS Update explains how to upgrade the software on the product.

which is also what I get when I disable the `\usepackage{titlesec}`.

In my actual document I have numbered subsections, but that doesn't make any difference to the *nameref* not working. The `\ref` returns the correct number in both cases.

Comment: Note that yuo should not be using `titlesec` with `memoir`

Comment: in texlive 2023 the output is correct.  And the problem is not really titlesec, but memoir which overwrites in memhfix the \nameref commands and so breaks it.  Try the fix mentioned here https://github.com/latex3/hyperref/issues/290#issuecomment-1621221223

Comment: Thanks, that workaround seems to work for now for texlive 2022, but it breaks the old build servers still on texlive 2020. I need to investigate this more.